# which design pattern should i use for executing distinct methods with respect to different objects?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

a class `A` has 3 `boolean` fields, and there is a set of objects of this class. i need to execute different processing for each object, in terms of the combination of its 3 fields. what pattern should I adopt?

```
public class A {
    boolean a, b, c;
}
```

thank you.

---

daniel

Comment: Do you mean one logic for `a=t,b=t,c=t`, another for `a=t,b=t,c=f` etc?

Comment: If you need to do different operations dependending on all three states I would implement a Strategy for each different Operation and select the right strategy via a switch or by a factory

Comment: @KroaX that switch what needs to be implemented by a pattern. I would use registry, a map from tuple(bool,bool,bool) to handler.

Comment: @MiserableVariable yes, that's it.

Answer (score 1):

Look up `registry` pattern. Essentially you define an interface `AHandler` and implement it for each combination you want to process.

Then, create a `Map<A, AHandler>` and statically initialize it with the handlers. Look up this map to find the handler to process each combination.

Comment: i just simplified the problem: there are a lot of `A` objects, not only 8 objects, `A`'s `equal` method is not determined by the three fields, and so i need to determine the fields combination of some `A` object to classify its type and then do some action.

Comment: You don't have to do it exactly this way; I didn't even give an exact way :) The basic idea is to have a handler interface and a map from something to the handler instances. There are variations where you clone the handler if contains state.